# Unable to navigate application on build

Tags: reactjs, vite, desktop-application, tauri

I have a tauri app built with react, when I run it with "npm run tauri dev" it works fine but when I run the build command "npm run tauri build" and run the application it responds to my login request but does not redirect.

tauri.conf.json

```
"build": {
    "beforeBuildCommand": "npm run build-desktop",
    "beforeDevCommand": "npm run dev",
    "devPath": "http://localhost:3333",
    "distDir": "../dist"
}
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "tailwind": "npx tailwindcss -i ./src/index.css -o ./src/output.css --watch",
    "dev": "env-cmd -f .env.development vite & npm run tailwind",
    "build": "vite build",
    "build-desktop": "env-cmd -f .env.production vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "tauri": "tauri"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you havenot connected the backend and frontend with their locations which is important while running the build folder